# How to select first alphabet of a word using SQL?

Tags: mysql

If the word spells let's say Doctor. How can I return the alphabet **D enclosed within parenthesis as follows:
(D)**

I managed to find: `SELECT LEFT(<column_name>, 1) FROM <table_name>`
but it only returns D (not enclosed within parenthesis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use string concatenation here:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT('(', LEFT(col, 1), ')')
FROM yourTable;
```